# utilinstall: Access denied when copying folder

Tags: service, installutil

I'm using installutil to install a service. However, when I copy the entire folder

```
- msawebservice
    - install.bat
    - MSAGRadWebService
        - MSAGradWebService.exe

- msawebservice - Copy
    - install.bat
    - MSAGRadWebService
        - MSAGradWebService.exe
```

The install.bat in the first msawebservice folder works, but when I run the install.bat in the msawebservice - copy, I get the System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'file:Path-to-msawebservice'. So it is trying to reference the old folder. But when I change the original folder name it still works correctly. Here is the bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX4=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX4%

echo Installing MSAGradWebService...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /i %~dp0\MSAGradWebService\MSAGradWebService.exe
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.
```

What I have tried:

- Unblocking the files

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this was that there was a space in the PATH. The PATH needs to be between "..."